# How to keep footer at bottom of page and centered with html & css?

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer won't stay centered or at the bottom of the page. It's either on the side or middle of the page, interfering with my other content.

CSS:

```
footer {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
  &copy; Copyright 2019. All Rights Reserved.<br>
  <a href ="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why did you add this: `margin-top: -0.5em;` in your footer css?

Comment: @Shuvo I believe I did that to see if I could use the margins and force the footer down but failed and forgot to remove/change it. I'm very new to html/css so I just fiddle until I make some sort of progress.

Comment: Please google `sticky footer`. There's tons of ready-made solutions for this.

Answer (score 2):

```css
footer {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  padding: 2em;
  position: fixed; 
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;

}


use `transfrom` and `left: 50%`
```

```html
<footer>
  &copy; Copyright 2019. All Rights Reserved.<br>
  <a href ="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set up a flexbox parent such as `body` and align items along a vertical axis. In this example, I add a `main` element which, using `flex-grow: 1`, takes up the most space available in the parent container. The parent is set to `min-height: 100vh`, which means it's at least as tall as the full viewport. The `footer` then consumes the leftover space. If the `main` content grows tall enough, the `footer` will be naturally pushed down the page.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main,
footer {
  padding: 2em;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: salmon;
}

footer {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique debitis, repellat adipisci, id facere quia sequi dicta corrupti necessitatibus quibusdam non nihil tempora, ipsum, sint. Voluptate a harum illo, non.</p>
</main>
<footer>
  &copy; Copyright 2019. All Rights Reserved.<br>
  <a href="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk104zx6/3/)

Comment: Didn't help with this issue, but did help me out with another one (centering my gallery)!

Answer (score -1):

```css
footer {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute; 
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<footer>
  &copy; Copyright 2019. All Rights Reserved.<br>
  <a href ="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
```

I hope this will help you as a solution.